# Finding the angle between the horizontal line and the inclined line

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

> A man is carrying a rod which has $2$ baskets at the edge that weights $10N$ and $6N$ like those depicted in the picture. If $AB= 8$ feet then find the distance of $C$ from A where $C$ is such a point that if the man carries the rod with point $C$ on his shoulder then the rod will remain parallel to the horizontal line.

Well that would be $8×6/10$ from the point A. So C will be $3$ feet further from $A$. Thus if the man carries the rod exactly $3$ feet away from point $A$ then it would remain horizontal.

Now I was thinking had not  carried the rod exactly at point $C$, rather suppose at point $D$ which is $4$ feet further from points $A$ and $B$. Then the rod would make some angle with the horizontal line.
[image]

Now I have tried to find the angle theta here. But failed. Any hint on how to find theta?

Comment: $\theta = 90°$: if the rod isn’t balanced, the resulting moment will cause it to rotate until it is—i.e., until the two weights are vertically aligned with the center of mass of the system.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the law of sines in right triangles. $$\sin \theta=\frac{\mathbb{opp}}{\mathbb{hyp}}$$

You know that the rod is the hypotenuse.

Comment: I have the length of the hypotenuse(rod) = 8feet. Now the opposite side also needs to be in the unit of "feet". How do I find the length of that side? I have one thought that as D is the center thus the rod would have stayed horizontal if the force acting on A would have been 6N as well like B. So there would be a net 4N force acting on point A. But how to use that info to find the length of the opposite side?